# Alguien me puede decir como puedo poner la imagen a mi gusto?

Tags: css, html5

Hice un `div` padre con 6  `div` bloques por asi decirlo, quiero poner unas fotos pero no me sale en la resolucion que quiero, alguien me puede ensenar como puedo cambiar la resolucion?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.cosas {
  display: flex;
}

.grupo {
  height: 19rem;
  width: 94%;
  margin: 0.7rem 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0 0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.2rem;
}

.right-1 {
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/bearded-happy-looking-man-with-brunette-hair-has-piercing-wearing-black-sweater-holding-pointing-finger-smartphone-copy-space-isolated-yellow-wall_295783-14549.jpg);
  border: black solid 0.1rem;
  width: 31%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cosas">
  <div class="grupo">
    <div class="right-1 grupo-m-right"></div>
    <div class="right-1 grupo-m-right"></div>
    <div class="right-1 grupo-m-right"></div>
    <div class="right-1 grupo-m-right"></div>
    <div class="right-1 grupo-m-right"></div>
    <div class="right-1 grupo-m-right"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: probablemente el ancho (`width`) está a máxima resolución, debes forzar un ancho para que no haga zoom.

Comment: Jjajajjaja sorry es que no lo sabia explicar muy bien, como lo explicarian ustedes?

Comment: "a mi gusto" es una expresión subjetiva, a menos que podamos leer la mente es difícil saber que significa. Serviría si pones el código que has intentado. "salen todas raras" también es una expresión subjetiva, a qué te refieres con raro (color,tamaño, ubicación)?

Comment: Tenés que ser más claro. _Me salen todas raras_, ¿en qué sentido? ¿cómo lo sabríamos nosotros, si no explicás qué es lo que buscás? Además, como te lo han mencionado, mostrá un [repro] de lo que hiciste hasta el momento.

Comment: Oigan banda. lo intente con el widht, pero no entiendo porque me sale igual... ya les paso el codigo y asi ustedes lo ven y me ayudan plis :)

Comment: Ustedes que me recomiendan hacer?

Comment: Tal vez [esto responde a tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197601/como-hacer-que-una-imagen-respete-un-contenedor-div)

Comment: Oye gracias amigo, no habia entendido el codigo hasta despues de 10 minutos jajajaj, utilize estos tres atributos y ya (  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: contain;
  background-size: cover;)